# setSummary() is not refreshed immediately

Tags: java, android, refresh, preferences, preferenceactivity

I have the problem that the summary of a `PreferenceScreen` is not refreshed immediately.

I have a `CheckBoxPreference` in another `PreferenceScreen`. I'm catching the change of the `CheckBox` value in `onSharedPreferenceChanged()` and use `setSummary()` to change the summary of the screen. But when I go back to the main `PreferenceScreen` the changed summary is not displayed, just the old one.
I have to scroll down and up again until its displayed. So once its out of the view and come back in its refreshed.

How can I refresh it immediately?

Part of my PreferenceActivity:

```java
public class AppPreferencesActivity extends android.preference.PreferenceActivity {

  @Override
  public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    if (key.equals("pref1")) {
      this.findPreference("screen2").setSummary("mySummary");
    }
  }
```

Part of my preference.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Category Title">
        <PreferenceScreen android:key="screen2"
                          android:title="Screen Title">

            <CheckBoxPreference android:key="pref1"
                                android:title="Pref Title"                                
                                android:defaultValue="true" />
  </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
BaseAdapter baseAdapter = (BaseAdapter) getPreferenceScreen().getRootAdapter();
baseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `onSharedPreferenceChanged` with `onPreferenceChange`

```
public class AppPreferencesActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements OnPreferenceChangeListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        //Set summary here
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't override `onPreferenceChange` in `PreferenceActivity`. I would have to extend `CheckBoxPreference` to a new class and put it in the preference.xml no? But thats a lot of code for such a small thing...

Comment: Modify `AppPreferencesActivity` to implement `OnPreferenceChangeListener` and then override.

Comment: Thats not working as well. I'm having the same problem, its not refreshing immediately.

Comment: I had to use `setOnPreferenceChangeListener` btw, just overriding didn't work. It was never called...